# which is faster?

Tags: cpu-architecture

which is faster and usefull ? accumulator , register , or stack?

Comment: They are all needed for a working system. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Registers are the fastest. An accumulator is also a register in which intermediate arithmetic and logic results are stored (info from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_%28computing%29)).

A stack will be slower since it's a region of memory, and memory will always be slower than registers.

However, you will always have more memory available than registers since CPU storage is very costly.

Bottom line: they're all useful and their speed is inversely proportional to their available storage.

Answer (score 1):

Those questions without any context about CPU architecture or other information what you want to accomplish cannot be answered in any useful way.

Usually the accumulator is just one of the registers - modern CPUs don't differentiate anymore, so for old one accu might be faster - or actually the only register allowing you certain operations. Registers are always faster then external memory, but there are just a limited amount of them (and they need to be explicitely named by the compiler/assember).

The stack is an area of RAM used to store data. So that's slower for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Quistion is not quite correct. "Fast" is related to the operations, not to the registers and etc. Another point - there is nothing about architecture of CPU in first message :-)

Depending on CPU architecture accumulator is a register but can have a special implementation. This way the operations that use accumulateor usualy faster than register operations.

About stack.  Some processors have no support of Register-Register operations(i.e. input-output processor). That case some operations on the stack can be faster because it is not required to calculate effective address.

Answer (score 0):

Register are always faster because it doesn't go get data into the memory, but be more clear about the situation.

Registers are usefull when you have many like x64 or Arm architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, registers are faster because they are actually part of the microprocessor. And the accumulator is just one of the register (the one that normally stores the result of various operations).

The stack is just memory like any other memory, allocated for the purpose of tracking return addresses and local variables.

But you can't use registers for everything because there are only a very limited number of them available.

If you explained why you were asking these questions, they might make a little more sense.